# Add cells to a table view with data from another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios4

I need a bit of help on a app i'm developing.

The app is containing two tableviews (two different xib files with view controllers), named RootViewController and addFavorite. Both of them has the subclass "UITableViewController".

The first uses CoreData to save the users favorites.
The other one collects a list of data from a txt file on the internet.

I know how to set them up seperatly, but I'm trying to make a app where you add cells to the coredata-list from the tablev nr. 2. The user should - when clicking on the "add cell" button in view one, be redirected to view 2, where the user selects a cell, wich is being added to the tableview nr. 1, and then is being stored in the core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just refactor you code a bit to abstract the data out into an NSMutableArray and populate your UI from that?

Comment: Thanks, seamed to be a better idea :)